# Unable to get Id of an Object(Item) in Jquery method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

when I'm running this code alert showing undefind. 
but if I'm trying to get other member it displaying properly.
i.e alert(data[row]['name']) will display the correct name.

```js
//this is the jquery method 

$('#search').keyup(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).val();
      $.get('/items', {
        search: textValue
      }, function(data) {
        for (row in data) {
          alert(data[row]['id']);
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
# This is my Rails ItemController. 

class ItemsController < ApplicationController 
  def index 
    if request.xhr?
       @items=Item.search(params[:search]) 
       render:json=>@items
     else
       @items=Item.all

      end 
    end 
end
```

```html
// this is the search form in index.html.erb page

<form id="item-search">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="query" placeholder="Type to search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) like this instead:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  $.get('/items', { search: textValue })
    .done(function(data) {
      for (row in data) {
        alert(data[row]['id']);
      }
    });
});
```